# name of the new mobile safari button

Tags: web-applications, ios, mobile-safari, ios-4.2

On the previous version (<4.2) ios safari, the way to describe how to add a webapp to the home screen (used even by apple on http://www.apple.com/webapps/whatarewebapps.html was "**tap the plus sign**, and then tap “Add to Home screen."

Now there is no longer a plus sign.

Is there a proper name for the 'share button'? It's main feature is an arrow but there are two other buttons with arrows.

Any ideas (or the official name) for this button?

Answer (score 2):

If you go into Interface Builder and play around with ToolBars, you'll notice that you can create default System buttons, and that one of them has an identifier called "Action". It has the exact picture you're talking about.

I'd call it the action button.

:-)

Comment: well this is to be used in instructions to less technical users. not convinced that calling it the action button makes it completely obvious which one i'm referring to

Answer (score 0):

I see it as a sort of "pop out of the page" icon. Or you could refer to it as the "curved arrow".